# DateSub function with decimals BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a SQL expression that computes someone's birth year. I'm trying to figure out how to make this work in BigQuery.

Here's the SQL Expression:

```
UPDATE table1 SET BirthYear = YEAR(DATEADD(month, FLOOR(Age * -12), convert(date, DateEntered)))
```

Here's what I have in BQ but it doesn't compute half years correctly:

```
UPDATE `Table1` 
SET BirthYear= DATETIME_SUB(DateEntered, INTERVAL SAFE_CAST(SAFE_CAST(FLOOR(Age) as FLOAT64) as INT64) YEAR)  
WHERE BirthYear IS NULL ;
```

Here's my table:

```
BirthYear   DateEntered          Age
NULL        2016-09-18T00:00:00  1
NULL        2020-09-18T00:00:00  0.5
NULL        2018-03-08T00:00:00  6.5
```

So if the age is 6.5 that would be equal to 6 years and 6months. Or 0.5 = 6months
Desired Results:

```
BirthYear                   DateEntered          Age
2015-09-18T00:00:00        2016-09-18T00:00:00  1
2020-03-18T00:00:00        2020-09-18T00:00:00  0.5
2011-09-08T00:00:00        2018-03-08T00:00:00  6.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below instead - so you transforms Age from YEARs to MONTHs and thus result is correct and as expected now

```
DATETIME_SUB(DateEntered, INTERVAL SAFE_CAST(12 * SAFE_CAST(Age AS FLOAT64) AS INT64) MONTH)
```